# How to add an entry for WiX bundle to View Installed Updates menu in control panel?

Tags: wix, burn

In general, a WiX bundle adds an entry to `Uninstall a program` menu in control panel. But, when I installed Visual Studio 2012 Update 4(It seems to be made by using WiX burn, maybe?) it added an entry to `View Installed Updates` menu in control panel. And I want my WiX update(patch) bundle (for my WiX installer bundle) to do like this. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `RelatedBundle` element similar to the following:

```
<RelatedBundle Id="PUT-GUID-HERE" Action="Patch"/>
```

Here is the [documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/relatedbundle.html) for the allowable values. If `Action="Patch"` doesn't work, try `Action="Addon"` (it's been a while since I tried this so I'm not 100% which one will give you the desired results).

Answer (score 0):

Set the attribute "ParentName" of Bundle element to your main product name. For example:

```
<Bundle ParentName="Your main product name" ...>
```